# spec.pgram equivalent in Python

Tags: python, r, scipy, signal-processing, porting

I'm working on some legacy code using R. In the code, frequencies and intensities of a periodogram are extracted and used for some downstream analysis:

```
spec.pgram(tdata,pad=0.3,tap=0.3,span=2,plot=F,detrend=TRUE,demean=TRUE)
```

with tdata being 1-dimensional time-series data.

The problem is that I would like to port this part to Python, but I am not able to reproduce the output of this command.

So far I tried to use the scipy implementation:

```
scipy.signal.periodogram(tdata)
```

and the implementation of the [pyspectrum](https://pyspectrum.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package:

```
p = spectrum.Periodogram(tdataA1n)
freq = p.frequencies()
intensities = p.psd
```

Unfortunately, both approaches yield similar "patterns", but with values of significant lower magnitude ( e.g. values ranging from 0-300 compared to 0-600 in R). I assume this is based on some of the parameters in R, but I don't know how to translate them to python.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody looks for a solution, I found a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/telmo-correa/time-series-analysis) with a python version of spec.pgram, which worked like a charm for me. Unfortunately it does not contain an explicit License, so I guess the GPL license of the original implementation is applicable.